# download a PDF with Javascript/Node.Js after generating data and storing the file into a path

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, download, loopbackjs

I created a generator for PDF files that creates the file and sends to a specific path automatically after creation. Still I want to download it right after but didn't know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated. This is my `generatorPdf.js` :

```
module.exports={
    pdfGenerator:function(data,pathfile){
        var fonts = {
            Roboto: {
                normal: 'server/pdfgenerator/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
                bold: 'server/pdfgenerator/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
                italics: 'server/pdfgenerator/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
                bolditalics: 'server/pdfgenerator/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
            }
        };

var datePaiements='';
var dateFinPaiements='';
if(data.abonnement[0].datePaiement!=null)
         datePaiements= new Date( data.abonnement[0].datePaiement.toString());
if(datePaiements!=='')
{
        dateFinPaiements= ('0'+datePaiements.getDate()).slice(-2).toString()+'/'+('0'+(datePaiements.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2).toString()+'/'+(datePaiements.getFullYear()+1).toString();
        datePaiements=('0'+datePaiements.getDate()).slice(-2).toString()+'/'+('0'+(datePaiements.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2).toString()+'/'+datePaiements.getFullYear().toString();
    }


var dateFacture= new Date(data.abonnement[0].timestampCreation.toString());
dateFacture= ('0'+dateFacture.getDate()).slice(-2).toString()+'/'+('0'+(dateFacture.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2).toString()+'/'+dateFacture.getFullYear().toString();

var PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake/src/printer');
var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
var fs = require('fs');

var dd = {
    content: [ ..............],
    footer:{.............}
}

    try{
    var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(dd);
    if (fs.existsSync(pathfile)) {//server/pdfgenerator/documentpdf/basics21.pdf
        fs.unlink(pathfile, (err) => {//server/pdfgenerator/documentpdf/basics21.pdf
            if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
            }
        })
    }
    pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathfile)).on('finish',function(){//server/pdfgenerator/documentpdf/basics21.pdf
    });

    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        return null;
        }
}
}
```

and this is my remote method in Loopback to send the pdf to a path and where probably I have to do the download of the file:

```
  cm_abonnements.getAbonnementById= async (options,req,res)=>{
    const token = options && options.accessToken;
    const userId = token && token.userId;
    try{
      if(userId!==null){
        let dataComedien= await app.models.cm_comediens.getComedienByUser(userId);
        let argAbn={};
        const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        var formPromise = await new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
          form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
            if(err)
            {
              reject(err);
              return-1
            }
            console.log(fields.key)
            argAbn.idAbonnement=fields.key;
            resolve();
          })
        })
        let dataFac=await cm_abonnements.find({where :{and :[{idAbonnement:argAbn.idAbonnement},{idComedien : dataComedien.idComedien}]}});
        var data={abonnement:[]};
        data.abonnement=dataFac;
        var str_date= new Date(dataFac[0].timestampCreation.toString());
        var nameFile= 'Fac_'+dataFac[0].idFacture+'_'+str_date.getFullYear().toString()+'-'+('0'+str_date.getMonth()+1).slice(-2).toString()+'-'+('0'+str_date.getDate()).slice(-2).toString()+'.pdf';
        var path='public/upload/Comediens/'+dataComedien.idComedien.toString()+'/factures/'+nameFile;
        createPdf.pdfGenerator(data,path);

        return dataFac;
      }
      return null;
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e);
      return null;
    }

  }
  cm_abonnements.remoteMethod(
    'getAbonnementById',{
      http:{
        verb:'POST'
      },
      description:'Get detail facture by number facture',
      accepts:[
        {arg:"options", "type":"object","http":"optionsFromRequest"},
        { arg: 'req', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'req'}},
        {arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'res'}}

      ],
      returns:{arg:'data',root:true}
    }
  );
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the following HTTP headers:

- [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type): `application/pdf`
- [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition): `inline; filename="download.pdf"`

Comment: Thank you for your help but where is that and how because I am using POST in the method. Can you detail a bit more please ?

Answer (score 0):

After data is generated and pdf file is stored, there are 2 steps left to implement the "download" feature:

1. Return HTTP response to browser, with `Content-Type` header as `application/pdf`, and `Content-Disposition` header as `attachment; filename="yourname.pdf"`. Normally, this would be handled automatically by web framework. I'm not familiar with loopback, so take Express for example:

   In `generatorPdf.js`, add a callback to listen the `finish` event:

   ```
   pdfGenerator:function(data, pathfile, callback){
     ...
     pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathfile)).on('finish', callback);
     ...
   }
   ```

   When `pdfGenerator` function is used, pass a callback function parameter. If the pdf work is "finished", return response to browser using `res.download()` (It's Express API, but I believe loopback has similar API as loopback is built on top of Express):

   ```
   var nameFile=...
   var path=...
   createPdf.pdfGenerator(data, path, function() {
     res.download(path, nameFile);
   });
   ```
2. In browser side, if it's an AJAX request (I guess so, as you mentioned it is a POST request), you need to handle the request with some blob operation. Here is an example snippet, with explanation comment:

   ```
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open('POST', '/download', true); // Open an async AJAX request.
   req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // Send JSON data
   req.responseType = 'blob'; // Define the expected data as blob
   req.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (req.readyState === 4) {
       if (req.status === 200) { // When data is received successfully
         var data = req.response;
         var defaultFilename = 'default.pdf';
         // Or, you can get filename sent from backend through req.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition')
         if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob === 'function') {
           // If it is IE that support download blob directly.
           window.navigator.msSaveBlob(data, defaultFilename);
         } else {
           var blob = data;
           var link = document.createElement('a');
           link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
           link.download = defaultFilename;

           document.body.appendChild(link);

           link.click(); // create an <a> element and simulate the click operation.
         }
       }
     }
   };
   req.send(JSON.stringify({test: 'test'}));
   ```